# Exact test for 3 x 3 contingency table

Tags: probability

I'm aware of the Fisher exact test, for determining the probability distribution for a $2\times2$ contingency table.

Is there an exact test for a $3\times3$ table? Or is there a way to combine the results of three Fisher tests, for each of the $2\times2$ tables for each pair of variables, so as to give an exact probability?

Comment: Maybe this will help ( Freeman-Halton extension of Fisher's exact test for method)? http://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc3/calc.aspx?id=59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Amzoti is right. Freeman-Halton fits the bill.

On-line calculators:

- http://www.vassarstats.net/fisher2x3.html
- http://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc3/calc.aspx?id=59

References:

- Freeman, G.H. and Halton, J.H. (1951). Note on an exact treatment of contingency, goodness of fit and other problems of significance. *Biometrika*, 38, pp. 141-149.